# The script needs to delete the unused volumes unless they have some certain values

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

The script needs to delete the unused volumes. If the volume has the

```
Tag Value Key : clean
```

and

```
Value : DND
```

then, it shouldn't delete it.
while executing the script, it delete the volumes which have the

```
Tag Value Key : clean
Value : DND
```

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='ap-southeast-2')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        for vol in ec2.describe_volumes()['Volumes']:
            if vol['State'] == 'available':
                if vol.get('Tags') == None:
                    ec2.delete_volume(VolumeId = vol['VolumeId'])
                    print("deleted:", vol['VolumeId'])
                if not vol.get('Tags') == None:
                    if not ((vol.get('Tags')[0]['Key'] == 'clean') and (vol.get('Tags')[0]['Value'] == 'DND')):
                        ec2.delete_volume(VolumeId = vol['VolumeId'])
                        print("deleted:", vol['VolumeId'])
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
        error_code = int(e.response['Error']['Code'])
        if error_code == 404:
            exists = False
```

Comment: What tags? What do you want to do exactlly?

Comment: The script need to delete the unused volumes. If the volume have the Tag Value Key : clean and Value : DND , then it shouldn't delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking only the first tag [0]. You should iterate over all of them to check:

```
for vol in ec2.describe_volumes()['Volumes']:
    if vol['State'] == 'available':
        if 'Tags' in vol:

            should_delete = False

            # iterate over all tags, not only the first tag,
            # to check if the volume should be deleted
            # or not            
            for tag in vol['Tags']:
              if tag['Key'] == 'clean' and tag['Value'] == 'DND':
                should_delete = True
                break        
  
            if should_delete:
                #ec2.delete_volume(VolumeId = vol['VolumeId'])
                print("deleted2:", vol['VolumeId'])
        else:
          #ec2.delete_volume(VolumeId = vol['VolumeId'])
          print("deleted1:", vol['VolumeId'])
```

Edit, as John metioned, it could be simplified:

```
for vol in ec2.describe_volumes()['Volumes']:
    if vol['State'] == 'available':
        if 'Tags' in vol:
          if {'Key': 'clean', 'Value': 'DND'} in vol['Tags']:
                #ec2.delete_volume(VolumeId = vol['VolumeId'])
                print("deleted2:", vol['VolumeId'])
        else:
          #ec2.delete_volume(VolumeId = vol['VolumeId'])
          print("deleted1:", vol['VolumeId'])
```

Comment: I wonder if you can just say `if {'Key':'clean','Value':'DND'} in vol['Tags']:`?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes, I think it would also work. Thanks for pointing this out.